# Bootstrap .modal() in React (no 3rd party) - 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

The goal is to be able to control Bootstrap Modal element via JavaScript **without using 3rd party libraries e.g. react-bootstrap**.

The app is created using `create-react-app`. The goal is to **not touch webpack config files**.

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Now when trying to use `.modal('hide')` getting:

[image]

The jQuery seems to be imported only once (with a `bootstrap` npm package). All other functionality and animations looks good.

May be one has to import `Modal` module explicitly from the bootstrap jQuery?

---

**EDIT:** To be more precise the `$` seems to have to methods at all and works only like a query selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the the '$' in your webpack.config.

```
...
plugins: options.plugins.concat([

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({

      $: 'jquery',

      jQuery: 'jquery',

      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',

      tether: 'tether',

      Tether: 'tether',

      'window.Tether': 'tether',

    })
})
...
```

Also make sure jQuery is in your package.json as a dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    ...
},
```

I'm pretty sure you still need to add it to your entry in webpack.config too.

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            ...
            'jquery',
            'bootstrap',
            ... 
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```